# Sending Json from React to Spring, Spring picks it up as plain/text and says does not support

Tags: reactjs, spring, mongodb, fetch

This is my controller in spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reg/", method = RequestMethod.POST , consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String createUser( @RequestBody Users user) {
        System.out.println("called");
        usersRepository.save(user);

        return user.toString();


    }
```

this is my fetch in react

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/reg/', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode:'no-cors',

     headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        userName:"tom",
        password:"meow",
        firstName:"tom",
        lastName:"jack",
        email:"fdafa",
        dateCreated:"jan1",
        age:"24"
      }),

    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify({
      userName: this.state.username,
    }));
```

I hard coded a json in there for teting purposes because I cant figure out what is wrong. I keep getting this error

2020-05-16 05:21:27.412  WARN 41671 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your `fetch` code but I'm 100% sure that it's the client (in this case, react) that's sending the wrong `Content-Type`. If you're using Chrome you can check the developer tools under `xhr`. I suggest you focus your efforts there

Comment: @TanKimLoong it looks like its sending wrong content type. I just checked chrome and its sending plain/text for some reason. anyway i can fix this?

Comment: I assume you're using node's fetch. Check their documentation for fetch for your node version. Maybe the one you're using is not up to date